# Prior for variances in dnorm in WinBugs

Tags: winbugs

I know that WinBugs uses precision as a parameter in `dnorm` instead of variance

```
 model {

    #Likelihood
        for(i in 1:N1){
            y1[i] ~dnorm(mu,tau)
        }

    sigma <- sqrt(1/tau)

    #Priors
    mu ~ dnorm(0,0.000001)
    tau~ dgamma(taumu, taus)
   }
```

My question is: if instead I want to specify the prior for `sigma` because I know its mean and variance would it be right to use the following model ?

```
  model {

    #Likelihood
        for(i in 1:N1){
            y1[i] ~dnorm(mu,tau)
        }

    tau <- sqrt(1/sigma)

    #Priors
    mu ~ dnorm(0,0.000001)
    sigma ~ dnorm(sigmamu, sigmas)
   }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can give `sigma` a prior, rather than placing it directly on `tau`, but it should be a sensible prior that cannot assume illegal values (e.g. `dunif(0, 100)`. Giving `sigma` a normal prior allows it to take on negative values, which will lead to errors.